# Can I turn off 2G support on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

From the commotion in the last several days/weeks I understood that a fake cell tower intending to play man-in-the-middle uses a 2G connection to avoid the authentication requirement (of the network towards the phone) that's part of 3G and up.
I would like to avoid such MITM attacks by turning off the 2G support altogether. I can live with it if my iPhone only uses 3G/4G, and refuses any service when only 2G is available.
I am using an iPhone 5S with IOS7.
Is there any setting or app I can use for that? (Preferably without jail-breaking my phone, but I know that might be a stretch.)

Johan

Comment: +1 for a company claiming to be all about privacy, this is terrible that they do not allow to disable 2G, especially while Google is beginning to allowing users to disable 2G for this reason

Answer (score -3):

Very simple; No way Apple will allow you to do this

Comment: If you have any information on this, a link or statement from Apple, it would be helpful. Otherwise your statement is not very helpful. From the massive amounts of replies I had already concluded that it does not seem possible, however..